# MVC nested views and partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am in the process of creating a prototype project using MVC 3 and I have come across a situation which I can't seem to find an answer for and it seems like I might be approaching the problem the wrong way.

A quick overview of my project; it is based on the MVC template you get with Visual Studio and I use the links (tabs) on the supplied _Layout view to access some of my other views. One of these links opens a second partial view that again contains links for more views (admin specific. hence the split). The problem I am having is that I can't seem to display views with the `@RenderBody` in the second partial view, which I understand is because you can't have more than one `@RenderBody` in a completed HTML file, which makes sense.

**So my question is, how can I display the views in this manner? Also, probably more importantly, is this the correct way to achieve this 'sub menu' system I am trying for or is there a better way to achieve this?**

Here is the relevant parts of the views, first is the 'main' _Layout  file:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Test App</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contracts", "List", "Contract", new { user=User.Identity.Name, page=1 }, null)</li>
                    }
                    @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                    {
                        <li id="admin">@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Administration", "Home")</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

When clicking the `<li id="admin">@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Administration", "Home")</li>` link, then the Home controller return the second partial view shown below:

```
<header>
    <div id="admintitle">
        <h1>Administration</h1>
    </div>  
</header>
<body>
    <div id="div-1a">
         <nav>
            <ul id="adminmenu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "List", "Contact")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="div-1c">
        <h1>Test</h1>   
    </div>
    <section id="adminmain">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</body>
```

When I try and run the code, it fails due to the second `@RenderBody`, which is understandable.

If you need any more information, then please let me know.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you want to do in the `RenderBody()` of 'Administration' view?

Comment: @Mohayemin Show a View that will be returned by any of the `ActionLinks` in the Administration View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert

From

```
<section id="adminmain">
   @RenderBody()
</section>
```

To

```
   <div id="adminmain"></div>
```

From

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "List", "Contact")
```

To

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Contact", "List", "Contact", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "adminmain" })
```

And in `ContactController` `List` action return `PartialView()` instead of 'View()'.

Do not forget to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` in your view to make `Ajax` work.

And before all read [Roman's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897868/887149)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work as expected. While the view is returned, it is returned as a basic, unformatted HTML page on its own (i.e. nothing of my partial views exist). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you notice the `@Ajax` instead of `@Html` for the `ActionLink`?

Comment: Yes I used the `@Ajax`, but it only returns the unformatted view with the surrounding Layout views.

Comment: Just realised I didn't have unobtrusive ajax referenced in my view! It works now I have added the following: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: O yeah. Its my fault that I did not mention it in my answer. Sorry for that. I am modifying my answer so that others can have a quicker help.

Comment: Its fine, I should have realised myself... I think I am getting ahead of myself! Trying to do too much too soon! Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You can not use `@RenderBody()` multiple times. One `@RenderBody()` in your main _Layout file is fair enough. In your second view use instead `@RenderPartial()` or `@RenderAction`.

**UPDATE** (based on first comment)

Let's say you want to render `/Administrator/TheAction`, so you will call

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("TheAction", "Administrator");
}
```

`TheAction` action will look like this:

```
public PartialViewResult TheAction() {
    return PartialView();
}
```

And it will render the view in `~/Views/Administrator/TheAction.cshtml` right inside the place from which you called the `RenderAction()`.

The importance is that it does not accomplish another `@RenderBody`. As you can see in `TheAction()` example, you are returning **PartialViewResult**, which does not have any `@RenderBody()` helper.

Comment: I looked into `@RenderPartial`, but it doesn't seem to be able to call a specific controller action, so I will try `@RenderAction`. However, how do you determine the location of the returned view? As in what `@RenderBody` accomplishes in the main partial view. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, however if I changed my `@Html.ActionLink` to `@RenderAction()` then the returned view would be placed within the `<li>` block, but I want it to appear in the `@section` block which currently holds the incorrect `@RenderBody`. This is why I think I might be going about this the wrong way!

Comment: I think you didn't understand my post correctly, try to read it few times more. Maybe you should consider reading something about partial views.

Comment: I understand the concept of partial views and how they work, it was just in this particular case I was a bit stuck, hence me questioning my use of them in this case. @Mohayemin below seems to have a possible solution. I guess I wasn't clear enough that I want the view to be shown when a user invokes it via an `ActionLink`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which incorporates both @Roman Mazur and @Mohayemin's answers with an AJAX call.

I changed my View to the following as Roman suggested:

```
public PartialViewResult List() {
    return PartialView();
}
```

I then changed the section to a div as Mohayemin suggested:

```
<div id="adminmain"></div>
```

I then created a link that invokes an AJAX script on it's click event:

```
<li><a id="load-partial">CONTACTS</a></li>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load-partial').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Contact/List/',
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#adminmain').empty().html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It works well, but I am always open to more suggestions on how to improve it.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something interesting when working with nested partial views in MVC4. Just in case somebody stumbles upon this..

When rendering a partial view in a loop,

```
@Html.Partial()
```

does not work.

Instead, use `@Html.RenderPartial();`
that emits the HTML instead of HTML encoded in the former case and works.

Cheers!