# Small MVC styling issue regarding ActionLinks and normal a-tag hyperlink

Tags: html, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have just solved an issue I had which couldn't be solved (to my limited knowledge) with an ActionLink so I used a regular hyperlink.

When these two links are rendered on the page, they are styled very similar to each other as they pass the same css conditions, however they aren't exactly the same in two ways that I have noticed:

- The text is selectable on the hyperlink where is isn't on the ActionLink
- When hovering over the ActionLink, the cursor changes to a hand rather than a pointer, the hyperlink stays with the pointer.

I was under the impression that an ActionLink renders a hyperlink which would explain why they are both styled by the css, but there are obviously some differences.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or suggest another solution to replacing an ActionLink with a hyperlink to call an AJAX function (which returns a PartialView)?

**UPDATE**

This is the rendered HTML. The first is the hyperlink, then second is the ActionLink.

```
<li><a id="load-partial">Test</a></li> 
<li><a href="/Contact/List">Contact</a></li>
```

The reason I have an id in the hyperlink is so that it will run the following script to create the view in a specific `div`. I can't seem to replicate this using an ActionLink as it just return the view on it's own without the Layout views and completely unformatted.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load-partial').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Contact/List/',
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#adminmain').empty().html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML for each case?

Comment: `<li><a id="load-partial">Test</a></li>`
`<li><a href="/Contact/List">Contact</a></li>` First on is the hyperlink, the second the ActionLink.

Comment: It's the `id="load-partial"` that is causing the different layout. You can remove this from your hyperlinks, or add it via an overload in the `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie Please see my update to my original post to see the reason for the `id="load_partial"` in my hyperlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ActionLink is nothing more than a server-side helper method that emits an HTML *A* tag.  There is nothing else special about it.

If you are seeing differences in behavior / rendering, view the HTML source that is rendered and look for differences there.

There are very few things you cannot accomplish with an ActionLink that would require you to hand-code the *A* tag.  Did you post a separate question about the problem you could not solve using it?

**UPDATE** (based on your posted HTML)

The hyperlink is missing a *href* so it will not do anything when clicked.

If you need to add an ID to your ActionLink, you can do something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact (this is the text)", "List", "Contact", 
    new { someQueryStringParameter = 42 }, 
    new { id="load-partial" })
```

That example shows how to generate

```
<a id="load-partial" href="/Contact/List?someQueryStringParameter=42">Contact (this is the text)</a>
```

Keep in mind the ID should be unique on a given HTML page.

Comment: Yes I did post another question, but I don't think I made myself clear enough and therefore had to try a different route: [Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897791/mvc-nested-views-and-partial-views)

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment about the differences between hand-coded links and ActionLink generated links.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already tried that, unfortunatly it just returns the view on it's own, without the Layout views and completely unformatted. I have updated my original question regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: If it returns a view without layout, then you are rendering a partial view rather than view in your controller action.  Make sure the List action executes `return View();` rather than `return PartialView();`