# MVC3 - Define where ActionLink should return its result to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, actionlink

I have an MVC3 project, in which, I have a page with 2 div tags, one of which is generated dynamically.
The dynamic div includes ActionLinks (which their function is generated dynamically). Each ActionLink should call the same function, the function will return an ActionResult, and this ActionResult should appear on the second div.
It's important to mention - the ActionResult may be very different from one ActionLink to another. One might be only a grid, the other include text fields etc.

Is there any way I can define the ActionLink to post the result to div, or alternatively, can a div in one view include another view?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I found the answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897791/mvc-nested-views-and-partial-views

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to do that through code behind, I had to use AjaxHelper:

```
    var aHelper = new AjaxHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "omg"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), writer), new ViewPage());
((HtmlGenericControl)ctrl).InnerHtml = (aHelper.ActionLink("[ButtonText]", "[MyPartialViewName]", "[MyControllerName]", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "contantDiv" })).ToHtmlString();
```

The "UpdateTragerId is where the content should be set into.
I had to use Partial view in order to place it inside a div of another page.